# How can i add progress bar on search button click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When i search results, my data takes some time to show,So i want a progress bar should show after click on search button.It takes 5-8 second to show data.If i add below div after [div class="k-grid-content] div in inspect element  then loading bar work well but not hide after data load.How can i add below code before data load and remove after load. Thanks !!

```
<div class="k-loading-mask" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
<span class="k-loading-text">Loading...</span>
<div class="k-loading-image"></div>
<div class="k-loading-color"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you have tagged your post as **Kendo**, then I am assuming you have used **AJAX** post to submit data to server. If that the case then you can use **AJAX Start** to show busy loader and **Ajax Stop** or **Ajax Complete** to hide busy loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kendo ui](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/ui) already provides a method for displaying a progress bar. You can use it like this:-

```
kendo.ui.progress(element, true);
```

Where `element` is the div on which you want to append the progress mark-up (You can add this div in some Master\Layout page).

Also, you can write a generic method in some common JS file like this:-

```
function displayProgressBar(display){
    kendo.ui.progress(element, display);
}
```

Finally you can call this from any JS function like: `displayProgressBar(true)` to show progress or `displayProgressBar(false)` to hide it.

Comment: Thanks Sir, for help me !!

Answer (score 0):

Add a gif to your view, set "display: none;" and then just add onclick(  [CODE]document.getElementById("loadingGif").style.display = 'block';)[/CODE]